# Justified Gallery destroy function (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, gallery, image-gallery

I have a question, how can I turn off "Justified Gallery" by `width`? On the right side of my web it's working nice (`min-width:1300px`), but then my css media(`max-width:1300px`) changes the design and my gallery goes to the bottom into a single line. I need it to stay with my original css (turn off Justified Gallery). I can't find this option.

Justified gallery works when `min-width:1300px;`
Justified gallery destroy all when `max-width:1300px;`

On resize it must start work again.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) and distroy or disable the gallery plugin.

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:1300px)", {
match : function() {
     // give your gallery destry function here
},      
unmatch : function() {}
  // init gallery function
});
```